# PHP save image from mail > Bogus DQT index 12 error

Tags: php, image, email, save, jpeg

in PHP with $structure = imap_fetchstructure(....) > $structure->parts
i will save images!

```
$fp = fopen('data.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $images['data']);
fclose($fp);
```

When i save the data to file and will open it i got the following decoding error: BOGUS DQT Index 12

What do i'am wrong?

Regards Kevin

Here the image data from mail: images array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => D01-1.jpg
            [mimetype] => image/jpeg
            [data] => ����JFIF���  1a�q1A�Q��������1r"B!�A����PPPp`p�����AA����������������������������������������������������������0 !���  
}AQ"a5r'C(�4+U-C6'( ��aq���Rbr���CScs���4DTdtIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�����������������������������������,<L\l|���-=M]m}���.>N^n~���/?O_o���0  
w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3/V'-�bCN_q���br���Scs���4DTdt���5EUeu���6FVfv���7GWgw�z���������������������������������������������������������^n~���/?O_o�����@���0!1�3����[�"���F��l�O@\�@$��ʸֵY0c��oή��pǎI�����NoC�"�J�g��I��e���'��s
�g''�q�x�&{�;��O�F��8��d�r�" �9 ��Td�<�T�ֈ
mY�uR��qZ+   �&wv�尧q�-��w������6�c�bB[�9����>�ܑ�-�A�O���H��e����6�R8�P�?�X����ۗ��G��E�xIIY�x�n�1���~����
�%�����an�=:=ChV�WD
3����Vw���R���(��m�f(�zp{�N5��M'K�`�DbJ����ޱ�t�v�X��Y��?/=:��U�+n������:@����T���A=���ߋ�-�(�F�Z�d��(�PTr:���Ztz=��6J���?0��w�)��c̖��U�z�sڧ�D����
ya�ŵ���͛x��l���v �kN1��
��"��Zn�e�hCHFq�*Ķ����`�� �Z��}�e�ݙ^�ƶ�:�ǩA+G�rxǷ�{dP�N�� �hʒ_[������V�:��D[ݴB�H�,
p�  <D�3�����k'f�2�y�G������F�Iu��hcGl��9�>��e.����    ���*��o��a�A����׳�,q�-n��<�?�b�LƭEY(��k�
�
���L=��<Z�6�1 ...............
        )
)
```

Comment: You miss an array level `$images[0]['data']`

Comment: this isn't the problem. I use this value $images[0]['data']